# GLFW application not getting focus under MacOSX

Tags: macos, opengl, glfw

I have an OpenGL application that uses GLFW under OSX 10.12.3.

50% of the time when I run it it works fine. When `glfwPollEvents()` is called from my main loop, the mouse callback is called correctly for mouse events.

However, the other 50% of the time it doesn't receive ordinary mouse events even though a window is correctly created in the foreground. The main loop is running but the mouse event callback isn't called. If I double click (two clicks within around 0.1s) then the event callback receives 4 events as expected. But it receives nothing for single mouse clicks.

Within the main loop `glfwGetWindowAttrib(window, GLFW_FOCUSED)` returns 1 when the code is working and 0 when it isn't. Adding `glfwFocusWindow(window)` after window creation doesn't seem to change anything.

If I switch focus to a different application and switch back then my application starts receiving events correctly.

I have used GLFW 3.1.2 built using homebrew, and GLFW 3.2.1 built directly from a github clone. I get the same behaviour either way.

For a while I thought `glfwWindowHint(GLFW_FOCUSED, 1)` fixed my problems but after the 10th launch or so the problem returned.

I'd like to avoid posting my code (whose glfw calls come mostly from tutorials anyway) and I'm hoping someone will recognise the symptoms I describe as some obvious mistake I've made. The double click behaviour seems like a big clue.

Comment: Did you try `glfwSetWindowFocusCallback()` out of curiosity? It sounds more like some other application trying to gain focus.

Comment: I haven't tried using that callback. I'll give it a go soon.

Comment: When I use glfwSetWindowFocusCallback() my focus callback initially gets called when the application works and it doesn't get called when it doesn't. When my application starts in its non-functioning mode, manually switching to another window and then back results in my callback being called once, with GLFW_TRUE, and from that point onwards it behaves as expected. In particular, it doesn't look like it starts with focus only to have it stolen by another application. Weirdly the double clicks (but not single clicks) can be received even when my focus callback has never been called.

Comment: Assuming you're setting everything up correctly. Then I can't see this being anything but a bug. [To which I recommend you creating a new issue on the GLFW repo.](https://github.com/glfw/glfw/issues) What's puzzling however, is that a bug like this would have been discovered and resolved ages ago. So are you completely sure you're setting everything up correctly? Any code would be helpful at this point.

Comment: Yes, I'd also expect this to have been seen long ago. Later I'll try to create the minimal version of the code that still fails. I can only imagine there's a 3rd party thing interfering though I did remove the "window manager" app that was running.

Comment: Ported code to SDL. Same issue. I think this is a generic Mac thing when creating windows from an application launched from the command line. Even things like the Python matplotlib libraries create windows in a messed up state.